# C++ new type initialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Let's say i create a new type like this:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> location;
```

Then how do i define a new location?
I now do it like this:

```
location end;
end.first = 1;
end.second = 2;
```

But is there a faster way?

Many thanks :D

Comment: You're not actually adding a "custom variable" but a new type.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry started C++ like this wednesday lol. Noted :D

Comment: @MrJLP A new type is *not* a new type, but a type alias, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregate initialization :

```
location end = { 1, 2 };
```

Or [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) :

```
auto end = std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

Or directly call the constructor :

```
location end(1, 2);
```

Comment: I've just re-read your question. Using `typedef` does not define a new type, but rather defines a new name (an alias) for an existing type. You would construct or initialize an object of a type defined by an alias the same way you would construct or initialize an object of the type the alias refers to.

Comment: Ahh allright, well it works which is basically what i was here for anyway :P